# lnk1104 : cannot open file 'libpng.lib', but 'libpng.lib' is the output, not an input

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, makefile, libpng, nmake

I'm trying to build libpng-1.16.6 as a static lib from VS 2010. I think I've ruled out makefile syntax issues, file system permissions and incorrect LIB/LIBPATH environment variables. The makefile is the unchanged makefile.vcwin32 delivered with lpng1616. I'm certain the issue is environmental, but am out of ideas as to what it is. I'm looking for fresh ideas! TIA for any assistance.

Pertinent facts:

1. The overall pattern is the same I've used to build geos, gdal and wxWidgets open source projects: A Visual Studio makefile project calls a Windows command file. The Windows command file does any required preprocessing, calls vcvarsall.bar to set up the VS build environment, calls nmake, and performs any required postprocessing. The command file is largely the same, but customized, for each project. The makefile in each case is the one delivered with the source code. A successful retest of my wxWidgets build proves that there has not been an environmental change on my computer causing the libpng failure.
2. The log output of interest is:
   lib -nologo -out:libpng.lib png.obj pngerror.obj pngget.obj pngmem.obj pngpread.obj pngread.obj pngrio.obj pngrtran.obj pngrutil.obj pngset.obj pngtrans.obj pngwio.obj pngwrite.obj pngwtran.obj pngwutil.obj 
   LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libpng.lib'
   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\amd64\lib.EXE"' : return code '0x450'
3. Explanation of the log output: Lib.exe is asked to produce libpng.lib from the list of object files. The error is that the output file cannot be open. At this point in the execution of the makefile all object files have been generated, which I have confirmed are present. The library is to be written in the same directory as the object files.
4. Since the compiler is able to write the object files, there cannot be a write permissions issue in this directory.
5. Starting a VS command prompt window, navigating to this path and executing the same 'lib' command line the makefile is executing succeeds. Therefore there cannot be a command line syntax error. Running the nmake from the Windows command file from this same VS command prompt also succeeds.
6. Adding the 'lib' commandl line to the Windows command file immediately after execution of the makefile results in the same error as when run from the makefile.
7. The natural conclusion is that the problem is the environment in which lib.exe is being executed.
8. Google results, searching on combinations of  'lib', 'link', 'lnk1104', '0x450', 'nmake', 'makefile', 'makefile.vcwin32', 'works in command line, not in makefile', etc., reveal several patterns. As one would expect, the most common problem is that one of the input files is missing or invalid. (See 3, 4, 5 and 6 above.) I haven't noticed a single case where the file cited in the error message is actually the output file, not an input file. Another common issue that something is wrong with the LIB or LIBPATH environment variables. (I've examined these, comparing the VS command prompt values with the ones from my workflow.)
9. I've found that apparently lib.exe writes its output to the default output name and renames to the name requested by the '-out' option. If the makefile is altered to build 'tmplibpng.lib' instead of 'libpng.lib' the same error message is generated.

Comment: The Windows command file and environment dumps from both VS console and VS project: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xx5b71e0gnilusw/AACQcT5ncdLJmBbujwEdlQw3a?dl=0)

Comment: Someone in my office has noticed an error in the command file, a missing double quote in two lines:

if "%_FLAVOR_%" == "debug" (
 set _COPYDST_LIBD_="%_LIBDIR_%\%_LIBD_%""
) else (
 set _COPYDST_LIB_="%_BINDIR_%\%_LIB_%""
)

Corrected these are:

if "%_FLAVOR_%" == "debug" (
 set "_COPYDST_LIBD_="%_LIBDIR_%\%_LIBD_%""
) else (
 set "_COPYDST_LIB_="%_BINDIR_%\%_LIB_%""
)

This bug does not affect the central nmake issue.

Comment: Have you tried building projects/vstudio that is in the libpng distribution?

Comment: Antivirus.  Try running filemon.

Comment: Thanks. The VS files delivered with lbipng are an option if I can't get the makefile approach to work. However, I have a large number of open source projects to build so I'd like to use the same pattern for all if possible. The current pattern is already proven to work for geos, gdal and wxWidgets so I don't see why this one should not. As for antivirus, I'll try my build on another machine. If it's a virus more than likely the build will succeed on another box. I'm pessimistic. If a virus is interfering with this build I expect it would interfere with the geos, gdal and wxWidgets builds also.

Comment: I've discovered I can reproduce the same error from the VS console if I run the Windows command file from there. That suggests the issue is in the command file. Comparing that command file with those for geos, gdal and wxWidgets has not yet revealed the cause.

Comment: I noticed that VS 2010 delivers three different versions of lib.exe. I hardcoded to each of these in turn. All three fail in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I  thought I was being safe. When writing Windows command files I prefix and suffix all 'internal' environment variables with underscore characters to avoid collisions, for example, '*LIB*'. Apparently '*LIB*' is in use by lib.exe, though it's not in Microsoft's published list. Renaming this environment variable solved my problem.